# How to directly decode h264 stream in byte[] format with VLCJ

Tags: java, media, decode, h.264, vlcj

I have searched everywhere in the whole VLCJ project,only to find out the method to decode and play h264 stream.

The only available method is

```
boolean playMedia(String mrl, String... mediaOptions);
```

in which the MRL can be either a file path or a network address.

I use the udpsocket to receive real-time H264 byte stream and I hope that the VLCJ is able to provide the method to directly decode the byte stream and play.

So I hope I can use a method like

```
playStream(byte[],...)
```

Comment: isn't decoding handled by the h264 codec? VLC just uses it like a driver.

Comment: You want to write an H264 decoder in Java, yourself? Why not just have vlcj/vlc play the UDP stream for you? AFAIR UDP is deprecated in vlc, but it still works - you just need to pass the proper MRL to mediaPlayer.playMedia(...). For UDP, it is this format: udp://[[<source address>]@[<bind address>][:<bind port>]]

Comment: @caprica Thanks very much!I've tried you proposal but I'm a bit confused about the UDP method.To be specific,I made a H264-STREAM server in JAVA,using the UDPSOCKET and my customized receiving method is like dataReceive() to fetch stream in byte[] format,in VLC I set the address binded by the socket(like udp://192.168.173.1:8888) and nothing happened.Need I fix my method to suit with VLC?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure about UDP. Did you try udp://@192.168.173.1:8888? Also, when you use VLC, have a look at the messages window "View -> Add Interface -> Debug Logging" before you play your stream.

Comment: @caprica Thank you again,after binding the address with the  format of udp://@addr:port,my vlcj was able to play the stream.